# Drop down menu with protected sheet

Tags: excel

I need your help.
I have a little file Excel.
This file has protected sheets with drop down menu and these are the steps:

1)double click to show Userform1;
2)click on CommandButton of the Userform to write on the protected sheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    
    Range("a1") = "prova"
    
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password", DrawingObjects:=True
    
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

The problem is that when I fix manually protected sheets, double click on cells with drop down menu  does work, but after I execute the "Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()" procedure, drop down menu doesn't work any more.
Is it possible to force drop down menu to work also after I execute the procedure triggered by CommandButton1?
I need Userform1 to show after double-click event, also for the cells formatted with the drop down menu.

Thank you in advance

I tried changing parameters of the Protect Method, but with the same result.

Comment: Information looks scarce. Anyway: is protecting your workbook at opening an option? Because you can make your workbook protected and editable via macro on the opening using the UserInterfaceOnly option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing the double click with the right button